# IBM Notes | Mac OS High Siera | Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lsxbe in java.library.path

Tags: java, macos, lotus-notes

I'm trying to read the IBM notes email on MacOS High Siera. When I run my java program, it's giving me this error:

> Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no
>   lsxbe in 
>           java.library.path
>             at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1886)
>             at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:849)
>             at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1088)
>             at lotus.domino.NotesThread.load(Unknown Source)
>             at lotus.domino.NotesThread.checkLoaded(Unknown Source)
>             at lotus.domino.NotesThread.initThread(Unknown Source)
>             at lotus.domino.NotesThread.run(Unknown Source)

On Windows machine of my colleague, he just includes notes embedded Jvm and it works, but on MacOS there is no embedded Jvm and the Jvm folder has only three jars inside the `./jvm/lib/ext/` directory:

```
njempcl.jar
Notes.jar
websvc.jar
```

By including these three files in the eclipse project, I am not getting any compile time errors anymore.

Comment: I am having a similar issue. I have added these https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSKTMJ_9.0.1/admin/plan_notesinstallationdirectoriesformacosx_c.html to the PATH on my mac, but still no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following jars to my project from notes installation directory:

- njempcl.jar
- Notes.jar
- websvc.jar

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the environment variables `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the location inside your app. E.g.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Run Java app with Domino
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/HCL Notes.app/Contents/MacOS"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/Applications/HCL Notes.app/Contents/MacOS"
java -jar yourapp.jar
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Did you pick the right path? Older versions have IBM in the path. Not HCL